# command line argument giving invalid initialiser error

Tags: c, command-line

The following is part of the code I'm working on in which I pass the name of the file to be encrypted and assign the key via command line using commandline argument.

```
void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut,
const unsigned char *key);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

 const unsigned char key[] = argv[3];
 srand(time(NULL));

 aes_init();
 encrypt(argv[1], "/home/ankita/python/encrypt/outfile.encrypted", key);

 return 0;

}

void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut, 
const unsigned char *key) {
int i;
aes_encrypt_ctx ctx[1];
unsigned char iv[16]; /* initialisation vector */
unsigned char inBuffer[200], outBuffer[200];
FILE *inFile = fopen(fileIn,"rb");
FILE *outFile = fopen(fileOut, "wb");

/* pick a random initialisation vector */
for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
iv[i] = rand() & 0xFF;
fwrite(iv, 1, 16, outFile);

aes_encrypt_key256(key, ctx);
while((i = fread(inBuffer, 1, sizeof(inBuffer), inFile)) > 0) {
aes_ofb_crypt(inBuffer, outBuffer, i, iv, ctx);
fwrite(outBuffer, 1, i, outFile);
}
aes_ofb_crypt(inBuffer, outBuffer, i, iv, ctx);
fwrite(outBuffer, 1, i, outFile);

fclose(inFile);
fclose(outFile);
}
```

Now, whenever I try to compile this code, this is the error it gives :

```
In function ‘main’:
error: invalid initializer
```

Is the problem related to me assigning the key or passing the file name via command line argument? If yes, please help with the correct way of doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const unsigned char key[] = argv[3];
```

You can't assign to that because Only constant expressions can be used to initialize arrays. For that you need char pointer.Because what `argv[3]` contain not known/resolve at compile time.

```
const unsigned char *key = argv[3];
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
I made the required change but now, I see something different - 
     note: expected ‘const unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char **’

and the code still won't compile!

Comment: @user3659283 You can use first solution. Also using `memcpy` you can avoid `const` keyword.

Comment: In function ‘main’:
warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memcpy’ [enabled by default]
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘encrypt’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
note: expected ‘const unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char **

More errors and warnings!

Comment: OK, I included 'string.h' and made some other corrections. Works perfectly now! Thanks a lot! :)
Btw, I used the second solution using memcpy.

Comment: @user3659283 - why not pass argv[3] directly to encrypt just like you did with argv[1]?

Comment: @user3659283 you can. what is problem?

Comment: @alvits - yea, actually! I can! I don't know why I thought of doing it in two separate ways! Its ok! Learnt something in the process. :)

Comment: @Jayesh - I just told you I used the memcpy solution because you seem to have edited it out of your answer.